# Why is this column becoming NULL when I simply print it?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a table with a primary key of 'pk'. I am using SQLAlchemy's merge to update a row in my table:

```
my_obj = MyTable()
my_obj.pk = 1234
#print my_obj.col1
DBSession.merge(my_obj)
transaction.commit()
```

I alreay have a row w/ pk of 1234. If I run the code as is the row doesn't change but if I uncomment the line where I print my_obj.col1 then col1 for that row in my DB will become NULL for that column but all other columns for that row don't change. Is this a bug in sqlalchemy?

EDIT: Here's my class for MyTable():

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker
from zope.sqlalchemy import ZopeTransactionExtension
import transaction
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

DBSession = scoped_session(sessionmaker(extension=ZopeTransactionExtension()))
engine = create_engine('mysql://myhost,etc here',echo=False,pool_recycle=3600*5)
Base = declarative_base()    
Base.metadata.bind = engine

class MyTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'my_table'
    __table_args__ = {'autoload':True}
```

Comment: What was `col1` before the `print my_obj.col1` line?  Do you actually give it a value when the `MyTable` instance is created?

Comment: All of the columns for that row had non-null values. Only col1 of that row got re-set to null.

Comment: Perhaps you could show us a simplified version of your `__init__` method?  Right now it is hard to reproduce your problem without writing additional code and making assumptions about what you've done.  An [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) would be helpful.

Comment: See my edits. Is that what you were after?